# How to store char pointers in Arduino to a variable

Tags: c++, string, pointers, arduino-c++

This is the code I am implementing. I am using an Arduino. This is part of a Azure cloud example.

```cpp
static void DeviceTwinCallback(DEVICE_TWIN_UPDATE_STATE updateState, const unsigned char *payLoad, int size)
{
  char *temp = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
  if (temp == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  receivedDesired = true;
  memcpy(temp, payLoad, size);
  temp[size] = '\0';

  // Display Twin message.
  Serial.println("This is temp");
  Serial.println(temp);  
  free(temp);
}
```

When I call this function it all works fine and the `temp` variable gets printed, but I want to assign the value in `temp` to a string variable. How can I do this? I have very little knowledge of pointers.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: What language are you using?  `C` and `C++` are not the same, and will result in different suggestions how how to address your issues.  For either language, include a [mcve].

Comment: sorry about that. I am using arduino code

Comment: don't use dynamic allocation in tiny embedded systems like arduino[

Comment: could you please give me a code as a explanation. That would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @eerorika - What alternative do you suggest when buffer size is not know until execution flow enters this function?  VLA is poo-pooed by many experienced in embedded.  Would this be a case where you would recommend it?

Comment: Pick one language, `C` or `C++`, delete the other tag.  The method to do what you are doing depends on language.

Comment: @I will give it a try

Comment: @ryyker If you absolutely need dynamic allocation, then I would recommend `std::string` in C++. But as pointed out already, you should avoid dynamic allocation. Are you sure that you need a copy of the entire buffer?

Comment: `std::string str1(temp);
 Serial.println(str1);`   will this work ? @ryyker

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::string`, called `String` in its Arduino guise, assuming that `payLoad` is a CString terminated with a `\0` before the function is called:

```cpp
static void DeviceTwinCallback(DEVICE_TWIN_UPDATE_STATE updateState, const unsigned char *payLoad) {
  String temp(payLoad);
  receivedDesired = true;

  // Display Twin message.
  Serial.println("This is temp: ");
  Serial.println(temp);  
}
```

If payLoad isn't a CString, but has a known size (note that `std::string::string(const char* s, size_t n)` doesn't seem to exist in Arduino's implementation of `String`):

```cpp
static void DeviceTwinCallback(DEVICE_TWIN_UPDATE_STATE updateState, const unsigned char *payLoad, int size) {
  String temp;
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    temp += payload[i];
  }
  receivedDesired = true;

  // Display Twin message.
  Serial.println("This is temp: ");
  Serial.println(temp);  
}
```

In both examples, `temp` is a `String` object now; I hope that is what you were looking for.

Note that `String` also does dynamic memory allocation.